# Что будет если при работе скрипта перезапустить nginx

Tags: nginx

Есть скрипты, которые выполняются длительное время, сорвется ли их выполнение, если в это время перезапустить nginx? Просьба дать ссылку где про это можно почитать, так как на этот вопрос можно ответить да или нет и я не определю, что верно.

Answer (score 2):

Nginx можно перезапустить (`service nginx restart`) и перегрузить конфигурацию (`service nginx reload`). В первом случае Nginx обрывает все соединения, во втором - ожидает завершения уже установленных соединений, а новая конфигурация будет работать только для новых соединений. Второй вариант лучше как раз по причине того, что скрипты продолжают работать.

> Start the new worker processes with a new configuration
>
> Gracefully shutdown the old worker processes

[Документация](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/commandline/)

Теперь: как ведет себя PHP при обрыве соединения? По-умолчанию, скрипт перестает работать, но все же выполняет [register_shutdown_function()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.register-shutdown-function.php). Чтобы скрипт продолжал работать, нужно явно в нем сделать `ignore_user_abort(true)`. [Мана](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php)

Comment: а если скрипт запущен через cron, например для импорта/экспорта товаров, тогда он не оборвется без ```ignore_user_abort(true)```?

Comment: @shadow Если это системный cron, то к nginx такие скрипты вообще не имеют никакого отношения и работают самостоятельно

Comment: @Mike я имел ввиду php скрипт, разве он может выполнятся без nginx, если сайт на nginx?

Comment: @shadow разумеется, хоть из командной строки скрипт можно запускать. Скрипт на php, как и на любом другом языке, получает на вход информацию со стандартного ввода (и переменные окружения) а то что хочет сообщить пользователю выдает на стандартный вывод. Все что делает nginx, это запускает скрипт и заворачивает стандартный ввод-вывод скрипта в http протокол для передачи в браузер. Но скрипт так же может быть запущен любым другим процессом, включая собственно cron (если взаимодействие по http с пользователем ему не нужно)

Comment: @shadow, вы небось крон используете по типу `curl http://сайт.ру/скрипт.php`? Лучше так: `php /путь/до/скрипта.php`, но сам скриптик скорее всего придется немного доработать.

Answer (score 2):

В большинстве случаев стоит использовать сигнал `reload`, который заставит `nginx` перечитать конфигурацию. В этом случае *не будут остановлены* **текущие процессы** и оборваны соединения.

```
nginx -s reload
```

Полная перезагрузка

```
service nginx restart
```

Все соединения с клиентами будут оборваны до момента загрузки Nginx'а (обычно занимает несколько секунд).

*Где читать про `nginx` - https://nginx.org/ru/docs/